# Sources to study Bitcoin source code, more specifically its UTXO model C++ code?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoin-core-development

Can anyone suggest some sources to learn about the source code of bitcoin or similar tech which are using UTXO model for their transactions.

Comment: The best way to learn is simply to read it on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/

Comment: Is there something in particular that interests you about it?

Comment: I know the github source link but can't find out the source code of UTXO transaction model among the large pool of files.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to learn as much as possible about the UTXO model.